# Not able to traverse array of objects in javascript.Got output for first element only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var persons = new Array();
var person = {
  firstname: "Padma",
  Id: 1,
  Country: "India"
};
persons.push(person);
persons.push([person = {
  firstname: "Balaji",
  Id: 3,
  Country: "India"
}]);
persons.push([person = {
  firstname: "Sivasree",
  Id: 2,
  Country: "India"
}]);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = persons.length;
$.each(persons, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value.firstname + " " + value.Country + "\n");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>
  <p>JavaScript uses names to access object properties.</p>
  <p id="demo">


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you are passing *JSON Array* inside *JSON Object* and that JSON Object inside outer *JSON Array* but your structure should look like `[{},{}..]` so you can just use `persons.push({..` to push object inside main array.

***Demo Code***:

```js
var persons = new Array();
var person = {
  firstname: "Padma",
  Id: 1,
  Country: "India"
};
persons.push(person);
persons.push({
  firstname: "Balaji",
  Id: 3,
  Country: "India"
}); //this is same as above pushing json object inside json array
persons.push({
  firstname: "Sivasree",
  Id: 2,
  Country: "India"
});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = persons.length;
$.each(persons, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value.firstname + " " + value.Country + "\n");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Swati,can we do the tranverse using javascript alone without using jquery.

Comment: yes simply use `persons.forEach(function(value){
 console.log(value.firstname + " " + value.Country + "\n");
});`